# Luman Token has expired

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, laravel-5.3

In luman drop this message

```
{
  "message": "Token has expired",
  "status_code": 401
}
```

but I want owerwrite it, i can't find where catch the TokenExpiredException.
I write catch code in the handler.php but it doesn't work.

```
if($e instanceof TokenExpiredException)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'massenge' => "Token_has_expired",
            'data' => []
        ]);
    }
```